# Removing a specific attribute in an array of nested documents

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Excuse my English, I'm from Russia.

I asked [this question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373639/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2) in the Russian version SO, but they still haven't answered it.

There is a **record** collection that stores archival files. Here is its simplified structure (I omitted most of the attributes):

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "tomes": [
    {
      "number":1,
      "archive_number":1
    },
    {
      "number":2,
      "archive_number":1
    }
  ]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
  "tomes": [
    {
      "number":1,
      "archive_number":1
    },
    {
      "number":2,
      "archive_number":1
    },
    {
      "number":3,
      "archive_number":1
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to remove the **archive_number** attribute from each of the nested documents of the **tomes** array for all documents in the **record** collection.

After deletion, the structure should look like this:

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "tomes": [
    {
      "number":1,
    },
    {
      "number":2,
    }
  ]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
  "tomes": [
    {
      "number":1,
    },
    {
      "number":2,
    },
    {
      "number":3,
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to write a query like this:

```
db.record.update(
  {
    "tomes": {
      $elemMatch:{
        "archive_number":{$exists:true}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: {
      "tomes.$.archive_number":1
    }
  },
  false, true
)
```

But this query only removes the **archive_number** attribute on one volume per archive case. I.e., after launch, we will see the following picture:

```json
{
  "_id": 1,
  "tomes": [
    {
      "number":1,
    },
    {
      "number":2,
      "archive_number":1
    }
  ]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
  "tomes": [
    {
      "number":1,
    },
    {
      "number":2,
      "archive_number":1
    },
    {
      "number":3,
      "archive_number":1
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please tell me how to delete all volumes? I don’t know how to correct the request, but my head doesn’t understand anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

With [`$[<indentifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) (filtered positional operator) and `arrayFilters` to update the document(s) in the array.

```
db.collection.update({
  "tomes": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "archive_number": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $unset: {
    "tomes.$[tome].archive_number": 1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "tome.archive_number": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j23Wlk1PcA6)

---

### Solution 2

With [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) (all positional operator).

> The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "tomes": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "archive_number": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $unset: {
    "tomes.$[].archive_number": 1
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S3-vDuMvW-F)

---

### References

[How the arrayFilters Parameter Works in MongoDB](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works great!